# Why do loop devices sometimes refuse to go away?

Tags: linux, dev, device-mapper

I regularly mount the partitions inside an image file as loop devices:

```
sudo kpartx -a test.img
```

That creates loop devices such as

```
/dev/mapper/loop0p1
/dev/mapper/loop0p2
```

When I'm done, I get rid of them with

```
sudo kpartx -d test.img
```

and usually the loop devices go away. But sometimes, they don't, and I don't know why. If I then do a:

```
sudo losetup -d /dev/mapper/loop0p1
```

losetup seems happy enough, except that the device stays. How do I get rid of them without rebooting?

Comment: When it does happen, are you sure `test.img` is still fully accessible and that no program had used it without passing by the loopback device?

Comment: The image file is still there. But I don't understand what you mean with "no program had used it". Is there a rule that it can't be? For example, I might install grub to the image file, while the partitions inside are still mounted via loop devices. Is that a no-no?

Comment: It would mean that the content of the file is different from what the kernel try to handle trough the loop device.

Comment: I would understand potentially undefined results. But not that I'm prevented from removing the loop device. (And I'm not certain that this is the right explanation; there seem to be cases where I didn't touch the image)

Comment: No, because it is likely to turn the kthread responsible for the loop device into an hung task. As long as the pid exist the loop can't get deleted.